# aws sync exclude not excluding all files

Tags: amazon-web-services, synchronization

The below `aws sync` command does execute, but I can not seem to exclude the `xxxx` files as that have the `--include` pattern in them.
It will always be `xxxx` but I am trying to exclude them from the `sync`. Thank you :).

**files in directory**

```
xxxx.id.1.bam
xxxx.id.1.bai
aaa.id.1.bam
aaa.id.1.bai
bbb.bam
bbb.bai
```

**desired**

```
aaa.id.1.bam
aaa.id.1.bai
```

**command**

```
aws s3  sync . s3://bucket/ --exclude "*" --exclude "*xxxx" --include "*.id.1.bam" --include "*.id.1.bai" --dryrun
```

Comment: I modified the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [order](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters) of `--exclude` and `--include` metters. It should be:

```
aws s3  sync . s3://bucket/ --exclude "*"  --include "*.id.1.bam" --include "*.id.1.bai" --exclude "xxxx.*" --dryrun
```